# Installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi: can't find packages

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.4.7 on Raspberry Pi (Model B, OS: Raspbian).

The guides I'm referring to are:
1. [RASPBERRY PI + SIMPLECV + OPENCV + RASPICAM CSI CAMERA](http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/59305587476/raspberry-pi-simplecv-opencv-raspicam-csi-camera)
2. [Raspberry Pi + OpenCV](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/)
3. [Raspberry Pi Rasbian + OpenCV](http://ariandy1.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/raspberry-pi-rasbian-opencv/)
4. [Setting everything up for OpenCV – Raspberry Pi](http://denis.doublebuffer.net/lablog/2012/08/10/setting-everything-up-for-opencv-raspberry-pi/)

The problem is that I can't install all the required packages in order to be able to install OpenCV since I get the error:`E: Unable to locate package package_name`.

Here the list of packages I can't install (output of raspbian terminal):
`Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libucil2

E: Unable to locate package libucil2-dev

E: Unable to locate package libpngwriter0-dev

E: Unable to locate package libpngwriter0c2

E: Unable to locate package libavcodec52

E: Unable to locate package libavformat52

E: Unable to locate package libswscale0`

Can anybody help me to get throughout this?

Additional information:
I'm connecting to Raspberry Pi through SSH (using PUTTY on Windows 7).
Raspberry Pi is correctly connected to internet through ethernet (I tested the connection using the midori web browser on raspbian).
I've tried several solutions found on the net but none solved the problem.

Comment: there is also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ - if you want to post it there.

Comment: Have a look here for further information: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11906/10788

Answer (score 2):

First run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run the `install` commands.

This will add all the available packages to your package index. Then your package manager will be able to find the packages in the index, and so install them.

Comment: Have a look here for further information: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11906/10788